# SQL Server : select where following (sequence) rows with the same column value as current column equal to parameters

Tags: sql-server

Script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table;
CREATE TABLE #GPIO ([NUM] TINYINT, [MaterialIntID] BIGINT, [ElementIntID] BIGINT, [DateAdded] DATETIME);

INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 8, NULL, '2019-01-06 00:01:14.190');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 8, NULL, '2019-01-06 00:01:26.023');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (6, 9, 11, '2019-01-06 03:29:07.840');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 8, NULL, '2019-01-06 03:40:33.300');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 9, 11, '2019-01-06 03:40:33.300');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 8, NULL, '2019-01-06 03:50:18.490');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 9, 17, '2019-01-06 03:50:18.490');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 8, NULL, '2019-01-06 03:52:33.303');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 9, 5, '2019-01-06 03:52:33.303');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 8, NULL, '2019-01-06 03:55:28.417');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 9, 10, '2019-01-06 03:55:28.417');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 9, 7, '2019-01-06 03:56:35.370');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 9, 2, '2019-01-06 03:57:36.370');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 9, 5,'2019-01-06 04:01:15.127');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 9, 7, '2019-01-06 03:58:35.370');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 9, 7,'2019-01-06 04:01:16.127');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 8, 7,'2019-01-06 04:01:17.127');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (5, 9, 7,'2019-01-06 04:01:18.127');
INSERT INTO #GPIO VALUES (4, 9, 7, '2019-01-06 04:01:00.370');
```

And I have these declarations:

```
CASE 1    
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @SameNum BIT = 0,
    @Counti INT = 2;
```

[Results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIBe1.png)

```
CASE 2    
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @SameNum BIT = 0,
    @Counti INT = 3;
```

[Results 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0avW.png)

```
CASE 3
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = 9,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @SameNum BIT = 0,
    @Counti INT = 2;
```

[Results 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reSei.png)

```
CASE 4
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = 9,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = 7,
    @SameNum BIT = 0,
    @Counti INT = 2;
```

[Results 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc8sQ.png)

```
CASE 5
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = 9,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = 7,
    @SameNum BIT = 1,
    @Counti INT = 2;
```

[Results 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSIXD.png)

```
CASE 6
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = 9,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @SameNum BIT = 1,
    @Counti INT = 2;
```

[Results 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1PUl.png)

```
CASE 7
    @ActionDate DATE = '2019-01-07',
    @MaterialIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @ElementIntID BIGINT = NULL,
    @SameNum BIT = 1,
    @Counti INT = 3;
```

[Results 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpwM7.png)

I did this script but it only PARTITION by [MaterialIntID]. I need to consider also PARTITION by [ElementIntID] but only if i have parameter named @ElementIntID in the declaration and also PARTITION by [NUM] but only if i have parameter

the count must be at least equal to @Counti

```
;WITH [FirstList] AS
(
SELECT [NUM], [DateAdded], [MaterialIntID], [ElementIntID],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateAdded]) - 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MaterialIntID] ORDER BY [DateAdded]) AS [GRP]
FROM [Gpio]
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateAdded], @ActionDate)=1
)
SELECT [TT].[NUM], [TT].[MaterialIntID], [TT].[ElementIntID], [TT].[DateAdded], [TT].[GRP]
FROM [FirstList] AS [TT]
JOIN (  SELECT [MaterialIntID], [GRP]
    FROM [FirstList] 
    GROUP BY [MaterialIntID], [GRP]
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= @Counti) AS [HV] ON [TT].[MaterialIntID]=[HV].[MaterialIntID] AND [TT].[GRP]=[HV].[GRP]
```

Comment: instead of having data in such format, create DDL statement for temp table and generate INSERT statements to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I dont know how exactly to do that

Comment: CREATE TABLE #GPio (NUM int, DATEADDED DATETIME2(7), MaterialIntID INT, ElementIntID INT); INSERT INTO #GPio VALUES (4, '2019-01-06 00:01:14.190',    8, NULL). And insert all other records. Then modify your query to use #GPio instead of GPio. And now anyone can just copy/paste it and write you the query.

Comment: Ok i updated the post

Comment: Add expected result also

Comment: I chnaged the insert and added a case es and expected results

Comment: These are the current results, but what is the expected  output? In other words, when you declare these variables with the values from test cases, what do you expect to get? Can you provide real values. For any of test cases, or for some of them

Comment: Look at the main message (i added cases parameters with value) and expected output in screenshots after each case

Comment: When I execute query with your provided parameters, I'm getting the same results as you provide in the screenshot.

Comment: ??? But I didn’t included them (the parameters) in the query. I have different parameters in each case. And different results suppose to be.

Comment: I know that the results will be different with different param sets, could you please show exact parameters set + exact expected output (not the output you get from the current query). I still can't understand what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: Read on the post i update it each case include diferent value in parameters